# Safari 4: How to profile the code running when the page loads

Tags: safari, webkit, profiler

In Safari 4, I am trying to use the profiler to see how the time is spent in the code that runs when the page loads.

1. I enabled the profiler ("Start profiling JavaScript")
2. I load the page.
3. I stop the profiler.

At this point, this doesn't create a "profile" snapshot (while it does if I start the profiler after the page is loaded). Any hint on this?

Comment: I'm also interested in this.  I can profile an action without reload (ie. dragging a google map) but if I start it then reload the page, it doesn't create a profile, what use is that?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For code inside onLoad handlers, you need to enable the profiler programmatically. Add console.profile() to the start of the relevant javascript, and console.profileEnd() to the end.

Read more here: [Using the Web Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/UsingtheWebInspector/UsingtheWebInspector.html)

It's very similar to FireBug's profiler: [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/console.html)

**Update:** The Web Inspector link above 404s. Here's a more current document: [Web Inspector Guide: Timelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Instruments/Instruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH4-SW1)